# Rails 3 link_to to add multiple dynamic parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2.16, I've set up a route to #show a contact with a mandatory dynamic parameter.  Another route includes a redirect default in case no parameter is specified.

**routes rb** (edited to show `resources` line)

```
resources :contacts, :except => :show
match 'contacts/:id' => redirect("/contacts/%{id}/from"), :via => "get"
match 'contacts/:id/:category' => 'contacts#show',
  :via => "get",
  :constraints => { :category => /from|to|about/ }
```

This

```
link_to "From", contact_path(@contact, :category => "to")
```

generates this link:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/contacts/1?category=to
```

In other words, it is correctly converting the `:id` to be part of the route, but it is then appending `category` as a separate parameter.  The default route sees the path without `:category` and redirects it back to `/contacts/1/from`.

How can I write a `link_to` that will generate this HTML?

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/contacts/1/to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb:

```
match 'contacts/:id/:category', :to => 'contacts#show',
    :via => "get",
    :constraints => { :category => /from|to|about/ },
    :as => :something
```

and then you call

```
link_to "From", something_path(@contact, "to")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reply! Can you explain why I have to override the helper name to make it work?  Without that override, it generates `/contacts/1.to`, in other words, it seems to treat the parameter as a format?

Comment: Rather than "override" I'd call it "clarify". You are probably using resources for contacts, so whatever you do "contact_path" is booked by /contacts/:id via :get. You need to define a fresh route for your purpose, and that route has to have a name for rails to be aware of how to use the parameters.

Comment: I've edited the original question to show the `resources` line in routes.rb, in which I exclude the default `:show` behavior.  It all works fine with the default `contact_path` helper except for getting that extra param on there. Just trying to understand why the default helper behaves differently than a custom helper.

Comment: I've seen it before, excluding the :show from resources does not release the use for the "contacts_path"... If you explicitly set it on a route, you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Stavros' answer works and may be the best solution. As another option, I realized that `contact_path(@contact)` is just returning a string, so without any modification to routes.rb, I can write

```
link_to "From", contact_path(@contact) + "/to"
```